# keep directory structure when generating files

Tags: go, thrift

I have those thrift interfaces:

```
./thrift/a/a1.thrift
./thrift/a/a2.thrift
./thrift/b/b1.thrift
./thrift/b/b2.thrift
```

where a1.thrift includes a2, b1, b2 (with `include "thrift/a/a2.thrift"`)

I generate the Go files for all those with `thrift -r --gen go:package_prefix=work -I . --out . thrift/a/a1.thrift`

It outputs:

```
./a1/constants.go
./a1/ttypes.go
./a2/...
./b1/...
./b2/...
```

**How can I tell thrift to output in?**

```
./a/a1/...
./a/a2/...
./b/b1/...
./b/b2/...
```

Note that I can move those files by hand but first I have many and second in Go **the package has to match the directories**, so I would need to edit those files. As an example the generated Go file for a1 will import a2 as `work/a2` and not `work/a/a2`)

Comment: What if you simplt specify `--out a`?

Comment: @zerkms it works but then I need to do it file by file, not sure if that's the normal way to go ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use namespaces. Add a line similar to the following on top of each IDL file:

```
 namespace go a.a1   // whatever you need, but exactly one per IDL file
```

Running

```
thrift -r -gen go a1.thrift
```

creates files under

```
 gen-go/a/a1/*
```